# Multisite on wamp unable to create a new site on first click

Tags: wordpress, wamp, wampserver

**The Problem:**

I installed Multisite on WampServer and when i click on "add site" the page go blank.

**Done so far:**

- Downloaded WampServer.
- Configured virtual host.
- Downloaded acrylic so i can have wildcard domain.
- Create database and installed normal WP
- Followed http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network and updated to MultiSite.
- Logged in.
- Clicked on My Site -> Network Admin.
- Clicked on Sites->Add New.
- Entered the required information.
- Clicked on "Add Site" waited 40-50 sec.
- Page went blank.

If i click on backspace or go back `<-` in the browser and then click "Add Site" again it works and i am able to visit the site,create post like a normal installation.

Any ideas would be wonderful.

Here are some technical details:

**My httpd-vhosts.con look like that:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName smallurl.com
  ServerAlias www.smallurl.com *.smallurl.com
  DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www2
  ErrorLog "C:/wamp/www2/logs/error.log"
  CustomLog "C:/wamp/www2/logs/access.log" common

  # - A few helpful settings...
  <Directory "C:/wamp/www2">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    # - Enables .htaccess files for this site
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www
  ErrorLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/error.log"
  CustomLog "C:/wamp/www/logs/access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

**My AcrylicHost.txt:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1   www.smallurl.com
127.0.0.1   smallurl.com
127.0.0.1   *.smallurl.com
```

**In httpd.conf:**

```
# Virtual hosts #yaniv#
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

`rewrite_module` is activated.

basically that covers everything.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Using Sub folders or subdomains ?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you got a `NameVirtualHost *:80` in your `httpd.conf`?

Comment: @LeonardChallis Actually the `NameVirtualHost` goes in the \extras\vhost-httpd.conf` file and only if you are still using Apache 2.2 as it is no longer valid if you are using Apache 2.4

Answer (score 0):

under apache|modules  turn rewrite on